# Compare two numbers and receive true or false?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select *, COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DATE,'%m-%Y') AS form_date
from incident_view
where (create_month = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
       and (create_year =  year(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))  
   OR (create_month = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
       and (create_year = year(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)))
AND CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = "Company"
GROUP BY CREATE_MONTH
```

Hello everyone,

The query I have above is working fine.

The result I get are some rows, but the important rows are:

```
COUNT(*)  | form_date
667          01-16
1964         02-16
```

I wonder if it's possible to compare the two counts of the last 2 months, whether the last month (02-16) > the second last month (01-16).
If 02-16 > 01-16 I want the result to be true, if not then false.

Would appreciate any help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of grouping by the month/year, use it in a `CASE` or `IF` when calculating the counts.

```
SELECT SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
              AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) > 
       SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
              AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS count_higher
FROM incident_view
WHERE customer_company_name = "Company"
```

If you want 3 different results for greater than, equal to, or less than, the best way is to calculate the sums in a subquery so you can name them and use `CASE` to return different values for each case.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN last_month > prev_month THEN 1
            WHEN last_month = prev_month THEN 2
            ELSE 0
       END AS diff
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
                  AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS last_month, 
           SUM(IF(create_month = MONTH(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
                  AND create_year = YEAR(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), 1, 0)) AS prev_month
    FROM incident_view
    WHERE customer_company_name = "Company"
) AS subquery
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Ehm I assume, that if the result is 1, the last month is higher than the 2nd last month or?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Isn't it clear from the `>` in the code?

Comment: Ehm Barmar, what happens if the values I compare are the same?

Comment: Is there any way to display then another number? Like 2?

Comment: Then it will be false, because it only reports true when the new month is greater than the old month. You could use `>=` to treat equal as true, that should be pretty obvious.

Comment: I've added another answer that return 1, 2, or 0 depending on the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
Select max(viewcount)
FROM (select * , COUNT(*) AS viewcount,
DATE_FORMAT(CREATE_DATE,'%m-%Y') AS form_date
from incident_view
Where (create_month = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and (create_year =  year(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))  
OR (create_month = month(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) and (create_year = year(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)))
AND CUSTOMER_COMPANY_NAME = "Company"
GROUP BY CREATE_MONTH);
```

Comment: This will show the maximum, but doesn't tell whether it's the last month or the second to last month.

Comment: It also doesn't return true/false as requested.

Comment: @Barmar
true I didn't read the question properly, I apologize.